# Transfer JavaScript to jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I collect a script to display facebook type multiply chat box. In this JavaScript code I used a Iframe to load chat page. But now a want to avoid iframe, and I am not enough knowledge about JavaScript.

So have any way to load my chat page by JavaScript for this script. OR if I transfer this script at jquery where is my problem below please?

JavaScript :

```
function register_popup(id, name, cmd, pmd)
        {
            for(var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++)
            {   
                //already registered. Bring it to front.
                if(id == popups[iii])
                { 
                    Array.remove(popups, iii);
                    popups.unshift(id);
                    calculate_popups();
                    return;
                }
            }
        var element = '<div class="popup-box chat-popup cy'+id+'" id="'+ id +'">';
        //if avoid iframe how to load chat page  
        element = element + '<div class="popup-messages"><iframe src="../chat.php?u='+ cmd +'" frameborder="0" id="iFrame1" name="CmainFrame" width="100%" height="249" style="overflow:hidden" class="if'+ cmd +'"></div></div>';
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML + element; 
            popups.unshift(id);
            calculate_popups();
        }

function calculate_popups()
        {
            var width = window.innerWidth;
            if(width < 540)
            {
                total_popups = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                width = width - 200;
                //320 is width of a single popup box
                total_popups = parseInt(width/320);
            }
            display_popups();
        }

function display_popups()
        {
            var right = 220;
            var iii = 0;
            for(iii; iii < total_popups; iii++)
            {
                if(popups[iii] != undefined)
                { 
                    var element = document.getElementById(popups[iii]);
                    element.style.right = right + "px";
                    right = right + 320;
                    element.style.display = "block"; 
                }
            }
            for(var jjj = iii; jjj < popups.length; jjj++)
            { 
                var element = document.getElementById(popups[jjj]);
                element.style.display = "none"; 
            }
        }
        //recalculate when window is loaded and also when window is resized.
        window.addEventListener("resize", calculate_popups);
        window.addEventListener("load", calculate_popups);  

//this function can remove a array element.
Array.remove = function(array, from, to) {
            var rest = array.slice((to || from) + 1 || array.length);
            array.length = from < 0 ? array.length + from : from;
            return array.push.apply(array, rest);
};
```

Tried as jquery:

```
 function register_popup(id, name, cmd, pmd)
        {
            for(var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++)
            {   
                //already registered. Bring it to front.
                if(id == popups[iii])
                { 
                    Array.remove(popups, iii);
                    popups.unshift(id);
                    calculate_popups(); //alert(popups(id));
                    return;
                }
            } 
        $("<div></div>").attr('id',id).append('<div class="popup-box chat-popup cy'+id+'" id="'+ id +'"><div class="popup-messages"><div id="iFrame1" name="CmainFrame" width="100%" height="249" style="overflow:hidden" class="if'+ cmd +'"><object type="text/html" data="../chat.php?u='+ cmd +'"></div></div></div>');
            popups.unshift(id);
            calculate_popups();
        }

function display_popups()
        {
            var right = 220;
            var iii = 0;
            for(iii; iii < total_popups; iii++)
            {
                if(popups[iii] != undefined)
                { 
                    right = 220 + 320;
                    $("#"+popups[iii]).css({"display": "block", "right": "right"}).show();
                }
            }
            for(var jjj = iii; jjj < popups.length; jjj++)
            { 
                $("#"+popups[jjj]).css("display", "none");
            }
        }
//others function remain same
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you do that?

Comment: Nothing display...

Comment: I don't see any reason anything _should_ display.  You never append anything to the DOM.

Comment: Your selector $("<div></div>") is wrong. You need to ether select all div's $('div') och a specific one $('your specific div by id or class')

Comment: A translation to better JS would've been a good first step. Only thing you gained in your translation was slower code.

Comment: See my JavaScript  code, its working well, open new chat popbox for each user. But In Jquery cannot open. Have any way to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't closely analyse your code, but I did notice this:

```
$("<div></div>").attr('id',id).append('<div class="popup-box chat-popup cy'+id+'" id="'+ id +'"><div class="popup-messages"><div id="iFrame1" name="CmainFrame" width="100%" height="249" style="overflow:hidden" class="if'+ cmd +'"><object type="text/html" data="../Cchat.php?u='+ cmd +'"></div></div></div>');
```

I don't know what you *think* that is going to do, but what it does do is create a div, assign it an id, give some children, and then throw the whole thing away.  Did you want to insert it somewhere?

**Edit:**

For example, you could write:

```
$("body").append('<div class="popup-box chat-popup cy'+id+'"...
```

(Find the body and insert in the new div at its bottom.)

or

```
$("#" + id).append('<div class="popup-box chat-popup cy'+id+'"...
```

(Find the existing div with the given ID append the new div to it.)

Comment: $("body").append( is working...